# When reading a text file with loop, it gives lots of white lines to console, and writes down lots of "H" to the text file

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
     fstream file;

     file.open("file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);

     file << "Ivan" << "\n" << "Ivan";

     string text = "";

     while (!file.eof()) {
         text = "";
         file >> text;
         cout << text;
     }

     file.close();
}
```

When I'm using `cout` to print that text to console, this gives me lots of white lines. And when I enter the .txt file, there are lots of "H" letters except for my text. I think the problem is in the loop.

[image: White lines]

[image: "H" letters]

Does somebody know what the problem is?

Comment: `while (!file.eof()) {` should be avoided and may cause a bug: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: You are writing to a file then read after the position you have written.

Comment: what is the content of the file?

Comment: There are two photos above the last sentense of the question "H letters" and "White lines"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `std::ios::app` flag. Passing this flag seeks to the end of the stream, so in your case you are already at the "EOF" of the file, that is why your loop fails.

Here is info from cppreference.com:

> app
> seek to the end of stream before each write

Try this:

```cpp
fstream file("data.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
if(!file)
    cout << "!file\n";

file << "Ivan" << "\n" << "Ivan";

string text = "";

while (file >> text)
    cout << text << ' ';
```

You can move back the read pointer to the beginning of the file after writing:

```cpp
file << "Ivan" << "\n" << "Ivan";

file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

string text = "";

while (file >> text)
    cout << text << ' ';
```